# Less boilerplate code when raising errors and logging

Tags: python, exception, logging

Let's say I'm writing a class an in setters of some properties I'm checking the validity of inputs. If an input is not valid I'm raising a `TypeError`, for example, but then I also need to log everything for debugging purposes. This results in me having to duplicate error messages.

For example:

```py
import logging
import datetime as dt
from dataclasses import dataclass


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@dataclass()
class Foo:
    start_date: dt.datetime

    @property
    def start_date(self) -> dt.datetime:
        return self.__start_date
    
    @start_date.setter
    def start_date(self, val: dt.datetime):
        if not isinstance(val, dt.datetime):
            logger.exception('Expecting datetime as start date, '
                             f'got {type(val)} instead.')
            raise TypeError('Expecting datetime as start date, '
                            f'got {type(val)} instead.')
        else:
            self.__start_date = val
```

So here I'm having to duplicate error messages. I could of course leave TypeError message blank and rely on screen logger to print the error, but this seems like a bad idea as the traceback will come with an empty error message.

Just asking on the off-chance there is a more elegant way of combining logging with exception raising.

Comment: Just raise the type exception, and have the user of `Foo` be responsible for logging with `logger.exception('')`; alternatively if you need both, you will need to call `logger.exception` and raise the error with `msg`, where `msg` is assigned with the same message.

Comment: also, don’t log it at the exception level, because `exc_info` param is then true and your log message will log a duplicate error trace (since exc is already raised). I would instead suggest logging at the error level which is one step down.

Comment: Also to de duplicate creating message, just assign it to a variable `msg` and then pass it to the new exc and the log method. If you want to go one step further, you can encapsulate this logic in a helper validation function as that’s pretty common in this case; the function will take a value and a type (in this case `datetime`) and if value is not of the specified type will raise an error with the same formatted message.